# How to convert Class<?> to Generics type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have one method which returns `Class<? extends Animal>`

```
public Class<? extends Animal> getAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    //....
}
```

A one more method that accepts generics in the parameter `passGenericAnimal(D animal);`

I want to get an Animal class type from `getAnimal()` method and I just want to pass to `passGenericAnimal()` method by converting it into generic type.

**Like this:**

```
public Class<? extends Animal> getAnimal()
{
    return Lion.class;
}

public <T extends Animal> void convertToGenericsAndAssign()
{
    T animal = getAnimal();
    //getting error here
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#15-of ? extends Animal> to T
    passString(animal);
}

public void passGenericAnimal(D animal)
{
    //....;
}
```

Is there any way to convert Class type to Generics type?

Comment: What is `D`? What are you doing in `passString`? Can you explain that in more detail? I think we need to know more about what you're doing with the class object to answer your question.

Comment: Actually, `? extends` could be anything there I meant it could be custom classes that I have created. For ex. An Animal is the parent class of All animals, I can say `Class <? extends Animal>`, isn't it?

Comment: Modified my question, I hope this will help you to understand the scenario.

Comment: You have to cast `(T)`, but there is no way to get this type-safe. You dont know anything about the `?` type, especially not if it matches the generic `T`. It will compile and work if the types match up, it will crash on runtime if they dont. That said, you are mixing different things. You say you have `Class<...>` but then want a `T` and not a `Class<T>`, those are two different things. A `Class<Lion>` is **not** a `Lion`.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you hints on how to make this compile, but I suspect that you are on a wrong track in any case. Even if your code compiles (and runs) it will probably not do the thing you assume it will do. However, for the moment, just the compiling changes:

```java
public Class<? extends Something> getSomeClass() {
    return SomethingSpecific.class;
}

public void convertToGenericsAndAssign() {
    Class<? extends Something> str = getSomeClass();
    // you are getting a class object. You need to actually store a class to make it work.
    passString(str);
}

public <D extends Something> void passString(Class<D> strType) {
    // ....;
}

public static class Something {}

public static class SomethingSpecific extends Something {}
```

I changed the type from `String` (which is not extensible) to `Something`.

As you can see with the example, the problem is, that you are actually getting a `Class` objects from your method. I am not entirely sure why you expect an instance of the actual object. *IF* you want to instantiate an object of that class, then the following code might help:

```java
public Class<? extends Something> getSomeClass() {
    return SomethingSpecific.class;
}

public void convertToGenericsAndAssign() {
    Class<? extends Something> someClass = getSomeClass();
    // try to get an parameter free constructor:
    
    try {
        Constructor<? extends Something> constructor = someClass.getConstructor();
        Something instance = constructor.newInstance();
        
        // Be aware, that the generic type `D` i smore or less just `Something`,
        // because the compiler cannot know at compile time, what subclass of `Something`
        // D should actually be. So it can just induce `Something`.
        passSomething(instance);
        
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // Handle , if the class does not have an empty constructor.
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // Handle, if the constructor is not accessible, or if the
        // VM does not allow reflection.
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // Handle, if the instance failed to be created.
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // Handle, if the metohd is e.g. private or something.
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // This should not be thrown, as you pass no arguments, but
        // you still have to catch it.
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // If the constructor threw an internal exception.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public <D extends Something> void passSomething(D strType) {
    // ....;
}

public static class Something {}

public static class SomethingSpecific extends Something {}
```

Comment: OPs `passString` method was taking `T` and not `Class<T>`. I.e. he wants to give the method a `Lion` (in his example) and **not** a `Class<Lion>` (which is of course impossible).

Comment: @Zabuzard I know, which is why I said 'make it compile', but not necessarily functionally what he expects. But I think that the compiling example might help OP in understanding the problem they are facing.

Comment: or you can just catch `ReflectiveOperationException` which covers all of them.

Comment: Sure, or just catch `Exception` altogether, but depending on the exception type OP might want different compensatory behavior. These are just catch-stubs.